# Weblate setup SES email for password reset

Tags: django, amazon-ses, weblate

I tried to set up a Weblate instance on AWS to send password reset emails. I followeed the following steps:

```
pip install boto
pip install django-ses
sudo vim /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Django-2.1.4-py3.7.egg/django/conf/global_settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
```

However it still doesn't work properly and I'm not getting any errors. my AWS key has a full permission to SES.

Update:

If i run send_mail from `./manage.py shell` I get this output:

```
>>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'xx@gmail.com',['xx@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/weblate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/weblate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/weblate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/weblate/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Hard to tell the problem without any sort of logs.

Comment: Try at least running `./manage.py check`, it will show you any connection issues (those should be visible in the admin interface as well). If this works, then there is issue with actual sending of email (not sure how the ses backend behaves and when it does verify credentials), those should be visible in the celery logs.

Comment: `sudo ./manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned `./manage.py check --deploy`, but you got the email error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're editing Django default settings, which is weird way to change configuration, but it seems that Bitnami is recommending this approach. It seems the setting is not applied properly as the test command still uses default SMTP backend.

Things to check:

- is setting actually applied: `./manage.py shell -c 'from django.conf import settings; print(settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)'`
- was `django-ses` installed into system? better run the installation as root `sudo pip install django-ses`
- aren't you mixing Python 2 and Python 3 environments (not sure how this is done in Bitnami images)

Comment: `sudo ./manage.py shell -c 'from django.conf import settings; print(settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)' ` returns 
`django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` It seems that settings from default settings aren't applied properly

Comment: Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: There should be `weblate/settings.py` somewhere and that's better place to apply configuration.